# Resize partition using parted

Tags: raid, centos6, filesystems, xfs, parted

There is a pretty big file-server(~85TB) running xfs file system, on Centos 6.9 which we use for our backups.

We were out of space, so I added 10 new similar drives to the array and rebuilt RAID 6 using Mega Raid Manager, which took nearly a fortnight. 
So, the total capacity is ~150TB and with the virtual drive it is ~135 TB.

I planned to use "parted" to expand the partition size:

```
[root@backup-serv ~]# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the
space (an extra 14649917440 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Ignore                                                        
Model: LSI SMC3108 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 150TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  90.0TB  90.0TB                  1
```

**Note**: File system does not display anything.

I have 60 TB fre space as shown below:

```
(parted) print free
Model: LSI SMC3108 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 150TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
        24.6kB  1049kB  1024kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  90.0TB  90.0TB               1
        90.0TB  150TB   60.0TB  Free Space
```

It shows there is 60 TB of free space. So, when I try to expand the "partition 1", I get the following( could not detect file system error).:

```
(parted) resize
WARNING: you are attempting to use parted to operate on (resize) a file system.
parted's file system manipulation code is not as robust as what you'll find in
dedicated, file-system-specific packages like e2fsprogs.  We recommend
you use parted only to manipulate partition tables, whenever possible.
Support for performing most operations on most types of file systems
will be removed in an upcoming release.
Partition number? 1                                                       
Start?  [1049kB]? 1049kB                                                  
End?  [90.0TB]? 130.0TB                                                   
Error: Could not detect file system.
```

df output:

```
[root@backup-serv ~]# df -hT
Filesystem           Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Root_VG-Root
                     ext4   107G   78G   24G  77% /
tmpfs                tmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            ext4   870M  154M  672M  19% /boot
/dev/sdb1            xfs     82T   81T  1.2T  99% /export/bak
```

Why is parted not detecting the filesystem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing CentOS partition using parted](https://serverfault.com/questions/760274/resizing-centos-partition-using-parted)

Comment: That solution is for systems with LVMs.

Comment: You can follow these instructions: https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the older version of parted was not great.

I used Gparted Live(latest parted version) on USB and booted it. That seems to make it work!
I was able to expand the partition using "**resizepart**".

Finally, after rebooting the filesystem was expanded using "**xfs_growfs**".

df output:

```
[root@backup-serv ~]# df -hT
Filesystem           Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Root_VG-Root
                     ext4   107G   78G   24G  77% /
tmpfs                tmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            ext4   870M  154M  672M  19% /boot
/dev/sdb1            xfs    119T   81T   38T  69% /export/bak
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us try an alternative command to see whether it is the bug of parted:

```
lsblk -f
```

or

```
blkid
```

Comment: Well you have found out it is the bug of parted. Why not try gdisk instead?

Comment: I think it was the bug of an older version of parted

Comment: I do not like parted at all. For the size calculation is always flawed.

Comment: It was not a bug. There was a debate years ago about if parted should be even doing that
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=807101